# How can i know which build number maven uses to deploy my snapshort version?

Tags: maven, maven-metadata

When i deploy snapshot version to Maven repository, maven automatically determines following fields (time stamp and buildnumber) .Time stamp is current number while buildnumber is oldBuildNo+1.

```
<snapshot>
      <timestamp>20170509.204524</timestamp>
      <buildNumber>1</buildNumber>
</snapshot>
```

Can i make maven to print it on console?

Comment: This is by default printed out on console during `mvn deploy` something like `Uploaded: .... /artifactId-Version-20170509.205454-9.pom` etc.